# How i can breakdown rating bar in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, ratingbar

I am making an android app in which I am giving a rating to a product. Ratings are displayed as per the below.

[image]

How can I design ratings like this? I am facing problems in how I can break down the rating as is shown in the above image. How I can breakdown rating in a horizontal line and then show a star there.

Please provide me with a guide me about this. I am new to this rating bar in android.

Thank you in advance

Comment: FIrst one is custom rating bar and second one is custom seekbar

Answer (score 0):

the rating breakdown image you given here is made with different custom controls.
I think you can use separate image for every star and show rating from database that how many person give 5 star,4 star,3 star,2 star,1 star. it's simple

Comment: how i can make layout like this

Comment: you have design it with relative layout{linear layout horizontal{2 linear layout}}

Comment: i have used textview for rating bar . then how i can assign average rating to this textView so that this can be chenged according to the rating

Comment: how i can custom seekbar without range

Comment: average=sum of total rating/rating count

Comment: for seekbar use image

Answer (score 0):

You can use something called "Horizontal Progress Bar" which is provided by Android. Here you need to use 5 horizontal progress bars. Please look into the link below:

https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/08/android-progressbar-horizontal-example.html